# Dreamweaver CS4 - SVN doesn't know I deleted a file

Tags: svn, dreamweaver, adobe-cs4

After a few commits, I decided to deleted a file that became unnecessary.
I did so, clicked the Site root, and clicked "Check In".

All the files that changed during the last commit are in that list, yet not the file I deleted. (afaik it should show it as Deleted)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can delete files from the repository. Switch to Repository view in the Files panel, select the file(s) you want to delete, and press Delete. When prompted, confirm that you want to delete the file(s).

from http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Dreamweaver/10.0_Using/WS80FE60AC-15F8-45a2-842E-52D29F540FED.html

Disclaimer: I use DW and SVN, but have never used them together.

Comment: That worked, however, it has many disadvantages, now I have to have an extra commit every time I want to delete something.

Comment: Now I downloaded a very old version of CollabNet's Subversion (1.4.6) to do stuff that Dreamweaver fails to do.